# Running a PowerShell cmdlet in a Python script

Tags: python, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a Python script and I want to run a PowerShell cmdlet. I've looked online and the only thing I can find is running a PowerShell script, but I feel like writing a cmdlet to a script and then dot sourcing it for execution would take a lot longer than needed.

I've tried using subprocess.Popen in the following way:

```
cmd = subprocess.Popen(['C:\WINDOWS\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe', ps_cmdlet])
```

But ps_cmdlet is a python string variable with a powershell cmdlet as its value. So, I'm obviously getting a "No such file or directory" error. Is there any way to run a powershell cmdlet in a python script without using things like IronPython?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This works rather well

```
import subprocess
pl = subprocess.Popen(['powershell', 'get-process'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
print(pl.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: WIth PowerShell Core 7, I'm doing `['pwsh', '-Command', 'Get-Process']` and it works perfectly! I don't need to detect the version or location of the `.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (ps_cmdlet is a python string):

```
subprocess.call(ps_cmdlet)
```

edit: Here is an example that will output your machine's ip configuration to Powershell:

```
ps_cmdlet = 'ipconfig'
subprocess.call(ps_cmdlet)
```

another edit: Another way that works for me is:

```
ps_cmdlet = 'whatever command you would enter in powershell'
p = subprocess.Popen(ps_cmdlet,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate()
```

Comment: I'm still getting a "No such file or directory error".

I'm just trying:  

    import subprocess   
    cmdlet = "start-service lanmanserver"   
    subprocess.call(cmdlet)

Comment: Are you sure the error is occuring at subprocess.call?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):      
  File "test.py", line 4, in ?
    subprocess.call(ps_cmdlet)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 419, in call
    return Popen(*args, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 550, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 996, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: This isn't a cmdlet example - ipconfig is an executable sitting on disk. It has nothing to do with powershell.

Comment: Try doubling up on the backslashes in your initial example - "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe". \ needs to be escaped in Python strings...

Comment: That doesn't seem to make a difference, either. I'm essentially getting the same error message.

Answer (score -1):

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen([r"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe", "get-process"],
                           shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process_output = process.read().splitlines()
```

Above script would help in executing PS Cmdlets from Python.